# Books for self-learning about statistic Simulation?

Tags: references, simulation, monte-carlo, random-generation

Preferably an introductory book, i.e. for undergrad (or notes or something like that) that explains concepts with detail and with lots of examples, without losing the formality.

That covers the topics

- Random numbers
- Generation of discrete random variables
- Generation of continuous random variables
- Monte Carlo method through Markov chains

Thank you in advance

Comment: I removed `[self-study]` tag, as it is meant for homeworks etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from [the bible](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/page/4/?s=devroye) of simulation techniques,

Devroye, L.  (1986) [Non-Uniform random variate generation](https://amzn.to/2P1Wogd). Springer

[also [available on line]](http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/),  you may consider

- Albert, J. (2009) [Bayesian computation with R](https://amzn.to/2IqTaS4). Springer
- Kurskche, J. (2014) [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis with R, Jags, Stan](https://amzn.to/2P4IdH8). AP
- Gamerman, D. and Lopes, H.  (2006) [Markov Chain Monte Carlo: Stochastic Simulation for Bayesian Inference](https://amzn.to/2Ugxjza). CRC Press
- Turkman, A., Paulino. C. and Müller, P.  (2018) [Computational Bayesian Statistics: An Introduction](https://amzn.to/2StFx6V). CRC Press

with the additional mention of my own books:

- Robert, C.P. and Casella, G. (2009) [Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R](https://amzn.to/2Gfd7JW). Springer
- Marin, J.-M. and Robert, C.P. (2011) [Bayesian essentials with R](https://amzn.to/2UGIKV5). Springer

Comment: Thank you. Though not sure why all but one from amazon